# Pandas: Drop columns where first n rows are all NaN

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, and I'd like to drop columns between index 100 and 200 where the first 1000 rows are all NaN.  Here's my incorrect attempt:

```
df.iloc[:1000, 100:200] = df.iloc[:1000, 100:200].dropna(axis='columns', how='all')
```

How might I do this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to reword your question, I am not exactly sure what you want, from what I understand, in your DataFrame, there are atleast 200 columns, in some entries all values from column 100:200 contain NaN values, and you want to drop all such rows that have  this given they are in the first 1000 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `thresh`

> :Require that many non-NA values.

```
 df.iloc[:1000, 100:200].dropna(axis='columns', thresh =1)
```